# Moves files with the same name to a directory and writes the counted number to the directory name

Tags: bash, shell-script, mv, wc

```
find /volume1/file/* -type f \( -name "*DF*" -a -name "*LIVE*" \) -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' file
do
    # extract the name of the directory to create
    dirName="${file%.E*}"
    count=$(find "$file" -type f | wc -l;)
    # create the directory if it doesn't exist
    [[ ! -d "$dirName$count" ]] && mkdir "$dirName$count"

    mv "$file" "$dirName$count"
done
```

Hi there,

I'm using another coder's shell script, but I modified it because I wanted to add more features, but it doesn't work

modified part `count=$(find "$file" -type f | wc -l;)`

For example, there are about 10,000 files in my Linux HDD, and among those 10,000 files, I read the file title before ".E" and create a directory with that title to move the files. Here, I want to put the number of files in that directory into the directory name.

```
EX)
artist.E01.DF.LIVE
artist.E02.DF.LIVE
artist.E03.DF.LIVE
artist.E04.DD.LIVE
directory name = "artist3"
```

I want to do this, but with the script I modified, only 1 is counted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Where do you want to search for what? `find "$file" -type f` finds all files under a path called `$file`. But as this is just a file, it can be found only once, so you'll always get a count of one.

(2) You probably meant to search for files named `$file` under `/volume1/file/`, but beware, if there were four files, then after moving the first one, there will be only three left, so you'll have a different directory name.

You probably want something like (untested):

```
find /volume1/file/* -type f \( -name "*DF*" -a -name "*LIVE*" \) -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' file
do
    # extract the name of the directory to create
    dirName="${file%.E*}"
    if test -d "$dirName"*; then
      dirName="$dirName"*
    else
      count=$(find /volume1/file/* -name "$dirName*" -type f | wc -l)
      dirName="$dirName$count"
      mkdir "$dirName"
    fi
    mv "$file" "$dirName"
done
```

Comment: Thank you it works well!! Thanks to you, I learned about the things that I overlooked.